# get array element by index javascript, ES6

Tags: javascript

I have an array `fruits = ['apple','mango','eggs','guvava','... many others']`. I have an index `15`, so I am currently getting element as `fruits[14]`.

Is there any way I can do the same using `.splice / .slice` or any `ES6` method.

I tried .slice(14,1) but not getting the desired result.

Comment: Why not just by index?

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible by .splice / slice

Comment: I think getting value by index is the best approach. I doubt if  any other way to get the array element without loop.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you can clarify, then probably someone can answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fruits.slice(14,15)[0] // => get you the value of fruits[14] and allocate new memory for a new array

fruits.splice(14,1)[0] // => get you fruits[14] but mutates fruits array and also allocate new memory for a new array
```

Comment: so .slice is a non destructive way, I assume.